# Select max is returning a wrong value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max

[image]

I have above table and I want to get the highest value from table bids `where bid_id=60` using the following query

```
SELECT MAX(offer_amount) as maz FROM bids WHERE bid_id = 60
```

**The problem is I'm getting the result as 80 in instead of the correct value which is 7000000**

Anybody with an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Aberrant case. Would you please share an **sql fiddle** ?

Comment: It's "correct". And store integers as integers and strings as strings

Comment: @Strawberry it have worked I have changed the amount_column from VARCHAR to INT

Comment: Well, of course;-)

Comment: You can get desired output by using CAST but what about if you perform SUM, AVG function in that column again you have to use CAST where ever you need and it's not correct way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store `offer_amount` in a numeric field (such as integer or decimal), not as text. Quick solution is to use the [CAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function in the query to cast the field's data type to a numeric one.

Comment: And we can tell it's a string, not a number, because the values are left-justified in the displayed fragment of the table.

Comment: Quick solution is to add 0 to the value

Comment: Changing offer_amount from VARCHAR to INT have worked. Thank you guys